# Update cookie is not working in nodejs with express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cookies

I have created a login cookie after login but when I try to update the data in that, it gives me an error

```
Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

My code is below.

```
/* Logout to main user. */ /* Not Working  */
router.get('/logoutToMain', mustBe.authorized('supportuser'), function (req, res) {
    var loginSealed = req.cookies[req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie];
    if (loginSealed != undefined) {
        iron.unseal(loginSealed, req.Security.CookiePassword, iron.defaults, function (err, unsealed) {
            if (!err) {
                unsealed.SupportUser = null;
                iron.seal(unsealed, req.Security.CookiePassword, iron.defaults, function (err, sealed) {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, sealed, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 432000), httpOnly: true, ephemeral: true });
                    }
                });
                //res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, unsealed, { expires: new Date(Date.now() - 1000), httpOnly: true });
            }
        });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Although when i remove this cookie, that works. (below code)

```
/* Logout action. */ /*  Working  */
router.get('/logout', mustBe.authenticated(), function (req, res) {
    var LoginCookie = req.cookies[req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie];
    if (LoginCookie != undefined) {
        res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, null, { expires: new Date(Date.now() - 1000), httpOnly: true });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Below piece of code is creating the cookie for a logged in user

```
var LoggedinEmployee = {
    EmployeeID : recordset[0][0].EmployeeId,
    EmployerID : recordset[0][0].EmployerId,
    EmployerName : recordset[0][0].EmployerName,
    AccountName : Employer.AccountName,
    EmpLevel : recordset[0][0].EmpLevel,
    EmployeeName : recordset[0][0].EmployeeName,
    CorpId: recordset[0][0].CorpID,
    Login: user.Login,
    Password: user.Password,
    SupportUser: null
};
iron.seal(LoggedinEmployee, req.Security.CookiePassword, iron.defaults, function (err, sealed) {
    if (!err) {
        res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, sealed, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 432000), httpOnly: true, ephemeral: true });
        req.ActionOutput.Status = req.ActionStatus.Success;
        req.ActionOutput.Message = 'Logged In. Redirecting to dashboard...';
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.ActionOutput));
    } else {
        req.ActionOutput.Status = req.ActionStatus.Error;
        req.ActionOutput.Message = 'System Error';
        res.send(JSON.stringify(req.ActionOutput));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read about node.js async behaviour. In this code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  console.log(1);
},0);
console.log(2);

output:
2
1
```

will be the output. why?
Because node.js run in a series of "ticks", which are execution instances in a queue running one after the other. Next instance cannot run before other is finished. Whenever javascript encounter a "callback" it pushes it into queue and execute the next statement. It is non blocking. setTimeout will "register" a callback and return immediately moving flow of control to next line. When this instance is finished next callback will be called.

In your code res.redirect('/'); will not wait for iron.unseal to be finished and execute immediately, sending the response. After that the callbacks will be called and res.cookie will execute finding that response has already been sent causing an exception to be thrown. Move res.redirect('/'); after res.cookie.

```
router.get('/logoutToMain', mustBe.authorized('supportuser'), function (req, res) {
    var loginSealed = req.cookies[req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie];
    if (loginSealed != undefined) {
        iron.unseal(loginSealed, req.Security.CookiePassword, iron.defaults, function (err, unsealed) {
            if (!err) {
                unsealed.SupportUser = null;
                iron.seal(unsealed, req.Security.CookiePassword, iron.defaults, function (err, sealed) {
                    if (!err) {
                        res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, sealed, { expires: new Date(Date.now() + 432000), httpOnly: true, ephemeral: true });
                    }
                    res.redirect('/');
                });
                //res.cookie(req.ApplicationCookies.LoginCookie, unsealed, { expires: new Date(Date.now() - 1000), httpOnly: true });
            } else {
              res.redirect('/');
            }
        });
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
});
```

Use promises or await to better your code and survive callback hell.

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil, I forgot nodejs works in async mode unlike .net, java. Silly mistake was done in the code :D